# Android webview in recyclerview blinking

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` in which embedded a `WebView` as a child. But I found that every time i call `notifyDatasetChanged();` the `WebView` will blink from blank to content. Anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: can you paste your adapter code here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

calling `notifyDatasSetChanged()` causes a `RecyclerView` to rebuild the contents of the view.  SO this is pretty much expected.

It is not recommended however to use `WebView`'s within adapter views such as `RecyclerView`or a `ListView`.

Comment: Why it is not recommended?

Comment: WebViews are extremely memory intensive. Having multiple instances on the screen may lead to OOM

Comment: I have one webview for banner and list string data. But then im implemented to RecyclerView additional adapter for my banner via ConcatAdapter, the list of data especially ImageView starts flickering. Maybe you have any ideas, any help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70752503/with-concatadapter-recyclerview-began-flicering